# Jexl arithmetic calculations are not accurate

Tags: java, calculation, jexl

I have an application that receives a list of JEXL expressions and evaluates them in the loop with data retrieved from the database. It does work, but calculations are not accurate. For example, this simple formula:

```
a*b+c
```

where a is integer, b - float and c - double.
with values a = 600, b = 6.287 and c = 102.245 result is suppose to be 3874.445 but JEXL gives me 3874.223. I checked it on couple hundreds of samples and error varies from 0.001% to 0.3% but I never got exact answer.
My JEXL engine looks like this:

```
JexlEngine jexl = new JexlBuilder().cache(2048).silent(false).strict(false).create();
```

I did put strict to false, because some data might be null and I don't want JEXL to barf on such data.
Any ideas why it is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is look at IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format. This implies that, even in pure Java code, you get a result like:

```
double r = 600 * 6.287f + 102.245d; // r == 3874.4451953125
```

A longer answer is that you can derive JexlArithmetic so that every operator converts its arguments to BigDecimal to obtain a precise answer. As an example, the following evaluates 'correctly' (note the 600b which makes the first number a BigDecimal).

```
  @Test
  public void testSO20230225() throws Exception {
    String src = "let a = 600b; let b = 6.287f; let c = 102.245d; a * b + c";
    final JexlBuilder builder = new JexlBuilder();
    final JexlEngine jexl = builder.create();
    JexlScript script = jexl.createScript(src);
    Object result = script.execute(null);
    double r = 3874.445d;
    Assert.assertEquals(r, ((Number) result).doubleValue(), 0.0000001d);
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use this suggestion. My application receives the formula and SQL query for the database. I do not know what will be column type and formula. It can be a concatenation of two varchar values or anything else. I retrieve values from DB as List<Map<String,Object> and then iterate through that list supplying parameters to the formula. Is there a way to make JEXL automatically convert numeric data to proper precision?

Comment: I guess I was not clear enough and I'm sorry I dont understand why the suggestion does not apply. Again, you *can* derive your own JexlArithmetic - to code your expected behavior -  and override all operators (add, mult, div...) to transform all numbers to BigDecimal to achieve maximum precision. Another solution is to do this conversion (transforming any number to a BigDecimal) when iterating through your maps, delegating all but the get() method that would convert any Number to a BigDecimal.

Comment: I did try, even before your comment, in the iteration through the list to convert 
if(o instanceof Number) o = ((Number)o).doubleValue():
Result wasn't accurate as well. Haven't try BigDecimal though. Will try it later today.

Comment: With BigDecimal JEXL does provide acceptable accuracy, but it is a big pain in the neck.